# Visual Studio C# multiple Button array

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

So in my Windows forms application (C#) i have a grid of button elements (btn0, btn1, ... , btn200) . I've been looking around for some time now but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

The question is how can I change the property of all the button at the same time.
At first I tried formatting a string like this: `"btn" + id`, (the id being the button number) so that I would have every button name in a string. But then I had a problem changing from string to button (type). Is there a way to do that ?
The other thing I tried to do was to create an array of buttons, but haven't had success with that either.

Is one of those two ways possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that the buttons are all in a control named parent:

```
foreach(Button btn in parent.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
  // do something with btn
  // eg btn.Text = "New Text";
}
```

If the buttons are directly in the form, use `this` instead of parent. If the buttons are in some kind of a panel, use `panelName` instead of parent.

The above works because as you stated, all the buttons share the same parent. However, if in some other scenario you have buttons in different parents (say panels), you would then need to do some recursion or specify multiple specific parents to loop on).

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Yeah, I don't understand the votes either, have I forgot something or...

Answer (score 0):

You can find it by

`Controls.Find("btn1", true);`

Where `btn1` is the name of the button (the string you generated)

Comment: And call that hundreds of times?

Comment: @Andrew Whats wrong with that, internally `Controls.Find` uses Dictionary. Since the OP already has an array of button names. This also take cares of recursive search

Comment: The name array approach is a very bad one already, and calling this hundreds of times is of course not something to recommend. What if you add another button with a different naming format? What if you have to continuously update some buttons' properties? The most logical option is to use the container's `Controls` property.

Answer (score 0):

FIrst of all why don't you use an array or List of buttons in place of button1,button2.

```
Button[] buttons=new Button[size];
....................
button[i].Property="value";
```

If you don't want to change then other option would be to use a linq query on Form.Controls like this,

```
var buttons = from button in Controls.OfType<Button>() where
button.Name.StartsWith("btn") select button ;
```

This will give you list of all buttons that matches your pattern.
or use "button.Name=="btn" + id" to get the exact button you are looking for.

```
var buttons = from button in Controls.OfType<Button>() where
button.Name=="btn"+id select button ;
```